# Is this a bug? Help me understand why it even tries to come up with this result

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log( Number.isSafeInteger( Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) )                       // false; makes sense
console.log( Number.isSafeInteger( (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) - 1 ) )                // true; makes sense, but should it return true?
console.log( Number.isSafeInteger( (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2) - 1 ) )                // true; does not make sense
console.log( (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2) - 1  === (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) - 1 ) // true; does not make sense
```

I would expect Number.isSafeInteger() to be programmed like Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + any non zero to be false.
As a user, I'd happily take Number.isSafeInteger( (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) - 1 )  to be false, since notSafe + anything should be not safe

Comment: `((Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) - 1) === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `true`. And `((Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2) - 1) === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is also `true`. Numbers are just stored as numbers - there isn't a field that is marked as "dirty" if they cross the safe integer threshold.